# Showing that a finite commutative ring with more than one element and no zero divisors has an identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Question: Suppose we are given that $R$ is a finite commutative ring with more than one element and no zero divisors.  It's standard to show that $R$ is a field, which I'm sure has been asked and answered numerous times.  In particular, since $R$ has more than $1$ element, choose $0\neq r\in R$, and multiply $r$ by itslef to obtain $r,r^2,\dots \in R$.  Then, as $R$ is finite, choose the smallest $n>m$ such that $r^m=r^n$ thus $r^m(r^{n-m}-1)=1$, and since $r^m\neq 0$, we have $r^{n-m}-1$, so as $n-m>0$, we have that $n-m-1\geq 0$, so $r(r^{n-m-1})=1$, and so we found a multiplicative inverse for nonzero $r\in R$, and as $r$ was arbitrary, we're done.  Now, to my actual question: Here, it was NOT given that $R$ even has a $1$.  For this proof to work, $R$ needs to have a $1$, so how can we show that such an identity exists in $R$?

Comment: Generally, the definition of a ring is taken to include 1, and the term "rng" (which is "ring" without "i") is used for a ring which doesn't necessarily have a multiplicative identity (an "i").

Comment: But what if, in this ring, we want to explicity show that $R$ has a $1$?  Could we do that, in this case, if it isn't given to us?

Comment: The duplicate I just linked deals with exactly this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can prove it has an identity. Take any element $a\ne 0$, and define $f:R\to R$ by $f(x)=ax$. Since $a$ is not a zero divisor, $f$ is injective. Since $R$ is finite, we conclude $f$ is surjective as well. In other words, $f$ is a permutation on $R$. The group $S_R$ of permutations on $R$ is finite, and so the element $f$ has finite order. Thus, there is some $n$ such that the map $x\to a^nx$ (which is $n$th power of $f$) is the identity map. So $a^n$ is an identity element of $R$.

Note that all you need is one element $a$ which is not a zero divisor.